# Generating Labels via Macros and loosing \ref{}'s

Tags: macros, winedt

I want to write a macro which will include labels.
When I generate a label with the macro I don't seem to have access to it in the list of Gathered resources provided by Winedt 9.

I really want the generated label to at least appear in my gathered resources.  I suppose I could leave this part out of the macro, anyone have a clean way to do this (within or outside of the macro is fine I guess)?

**Here's the MWE**

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \newcommand{\myFig}[2]{
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      Lame figure
      \caption{#1}\label{#2}
    \end{figure}
    }

    \begin{document}
    \myFig{caption is here}{myLabel}
    I want to reference figure~\ref{myLabel}. %myLabel does not pop up: see gif
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This may also be considered a feature-request in terms of the WinEdt editor, which you should probably send to [WinEdt Support](http://www.winedt.com/support.html).

Comment: What happens if you put `% GATHER{myfile.aux}` in the preamble?

Comment: Nothing happens if I add % GATHER{myfile.aux}.  I tried % GATHER{badLabelMWE.aux} and replacing the % with a \ and all combinations didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To collect your label in the "Tree" interface, follow these steps:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. Double-click the "Tree" item (`Tree.ini` gets opened)
3. Locate the lines

   ```
   BRANCH="Labels-TeX"
     BRANCH_CAPTION="Labels  (#)"
     // Change Mode from TeX to ? to disable this item
     BRANCH_MODE_FILTER="TeX|DTX;INS;STY;AUX"
     BRANCH_ICON="Label"
     BRANCH_SORTED=1
     BRANCH_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
     BRANCH_IGNORE_COMMENTS=1
     BRANCH_IGNORE_VERBATIM=1
     BRANCH_EXPANDED=0
     BRANCH_BEFORE_BUILD_MACRO="SaveSort;SetSort(1,1,1,-1,1,1);"
     BRANCH_AFTER_BUILD_MACRO="RestoreSort;"
     ITEM="\label{?}"
   ```

   and just after them insert the line

   ```
       ALT="\myFig{?}{?}"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

Now your label is collected in the "Tree" interface:

[image]

---

To collect your label in the "Gather" interface, follow these steps:

1. In the "Options Interface", double-click the "Gather" item (`Gather.ini` gets opened)
2. Locate the lines

   ```
   PAGE="Label-TeX"
     PAGE_CAPTION="Label"
     // Change Mode from TeX to ? to disable this item
     PAGE_MODE_FILTER="TeX|DTX;INS;STY;AUX"
     PAGE_SORTED=1
     PAGE_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
     PAGE_IGNORE_COMMENTS=1
     PAGE_IGNORE_VERBATIM=1
     PAGE_BEFORE_BUILD_MACRO="SaveSort;SetSort(1,1,1,-1,1,1);"
     PAGE_AFTER_BUILD_MACRO="RestoreSort;"
     PAGE_ON_ACTIVATE_MACRO="GlobalMark;"
     PAGE_ON_SHOW_MACRO="GlobalMark;"
     ITEM="\label{?}"
   ```

   and just after them insert the line

   ```
       ALT="\myFig{?}{?}"
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

Now your label is collected in the "Gather" interface:

[image]

---

Now your label is also shown in the "GDI Popup Interface" interface:

[image]

---

### EDIT

To add this functionality for a command like `\yt{}{}{}` where the last argument is the label (as in your comments), all you have to do is to add the line

```
    ALT="\yt{?}{?}{?}"
```

both in `Tree.ini` and `Gather.ini` as I did above. The Last wildcard (`?`) identifies the label.

Comment: Hi! Long time no see! Welcome back!

Comment: Ciao @egreg and thanks for your kindness. Unfortunately I lack time to be more present in the site, I will only have a look when I receive notifications by e-mail on my favourite questions :-)

Comment: Wow!  That was awesome!  
The real function I want to create these for is of the form: \yt{}{}{} (I embed a youtube video and the arguments are youtube hash, comment, label).  

To enable the "GDI Popup Interface" how would I change the code you gave me?

Comment: I don't understand the last bit enough to make it work for any function of my own.  But this totally works.  If I can get it working for any function that'd be super helpful.

Comment: @pefmath See the edit. I removed the part for active strings from the answer since it is not really needed for the functionality you need. :-)

Comment: @karkkoeller:  Thanks! That was the confusing bit.  The rest is clear and everything works!  Great answer!