# Calling the GDI Popup Interface with Own Macro to Pull Gathered Lables

Tags: macros, winedt

In this [Previous Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212847/generating-labels-via-macros-and-loosing-refs) I was able to gather labels with a Macro I created.

Now I've got the opposite problem.  I want to pull to pull up that nice GDI Popup Interface when I use a macro.

**Here's the MWE:**

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\myFig}[2]{
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      Lame figure
      \caption{#1}\label{#2}
    \end{figure}
    }

\newcommand{\fig}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1} (p.~\pageref{#1})}

    \begin{document}
    \myFig{caption is here}{myLabel}
    I am able to reference figure~\ref{myLabel} as usual, 
but want to get the popup using my new macro like this \fig{myLabel}.  

   \end{document}
```

The code works but I don't get the nice popup.  How do I get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you have to do:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. In the "Options Interface", double-click the "Gather" item (`Gather.ini` gets opened)
3. Locate the lines

   ```
   PAGE="Ref-TeX"
     PAGE_CAPTION="Ref"
     // Change Mode from TeX to ? to disable this item
     PAGE_MODE_FILTER="TeX|DTX;INS;STY;AUX"
     PAGE_SORTED=0
     PAGE_CASE_SENSITIVE=1
     PAGE_IGNORE_COMMENTS=1
     PAGE_IGNORE_VERBATIM=1
     PAGE_ON_ACTIVATE_MACRO="GlobalMark;"
     PAGE_ON_SHOW_MACRO="GlobalMark;"
     ITEM="\ref{?}"
   ```

   and just after them insert the line

   ```
       ALT="\fig{?}"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.
5. Now, in the "Options Interface", double-click the "Active Strings" item (`ActiveStrings.ini` gets opened)
6. Locate the lines

   ```
   STRING="\?ref{"
     ENABLED=0
     MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
     MACRO="[Relax;]"
     DBL_CLICK_ENABLED=1
     DBL_CLICK_MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
     DBL_CLICK_MACRO="[Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\ArgStart.edt');"+
                      "GDIShow;GDISetPage('Label');]"
   ```

   and just after them insert the following lines

   ```
   STRING="\fig{}"
     ENABLED=1
     MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
     MACRO="[Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Ref.edt');]"
     DBL_CLICK_ENABLED=1
     DBL_CLICK_MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
     DBL_CLICK_MACRO="[Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\ArgEnd.edt');"+
                      "Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Ref.edt');]"

   STRING="\fig{?},,"
     ENABLED=1
     MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
     MACRO="[Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Ref-cont.edt');]"

   STRING="\fig{?,,"
     ENABLED=0
     MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
     MACRO="[Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Ref-sel.edt');]"

   STRING="\fig{?}"
     ENABLED=0
     MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
     MACRO="[GDIShow;GDISetPage('Label','%?');]"
     DBL_CLICK_ENABLED=1
     DBL_CLICK_MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
     DBL_CLICK_MACRO="[Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\ArgEnd.edt');"+
                      "CharLeft;GDIShow;GDISetPage('Label','%?');]"
   ```
7. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

Now your `\fig` command is collected in the "Ref" page of the "Gather" interface:

[image]

and acts as you wanted, opening the "GDI Popup Interface" interface:

[image]