# Gathering items in WinEdt

Tags: winedt

I've defined my own command

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{%
\clearpage%
\section{#1}\label{#2}%
}
```

which I use as in the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{%
\clearpage%
\section{#1}\label{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mysection{A section}{sec:first}

A reference to section~\ref{sec:second}.

\mysection{Another section}{sec:second}

A reference to section~\ref{sec:first}.

\end{document}
```

I've been able to let WinEdt recognise my command as a `\section` and, thanks to the answer given by Karl Koeller to this question: [Generating Labels via Macros and loosing \ref{}'s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212847/31910), to let WinEdt collect the label associated with this command.

Now the problem is that WinEdt sees

```
\section{#1}
```

as a `\section` and

```
\label{#2}
```

as a `\label` and collects them as such.

This is how my document structure looks like in WinEdt's Tree with the above code:

[image]

Is there any workaround to let WinEdt discard the `#1` section and the `#2` label?

Comment: This would require parsing the arguments of `\section` and `\label` and it is not straightforward...

Comment: I don't have this editor but is the problem that the line with `\section{#1}` is explicitly in your document? what happens if you put the definintion in a file `mysec.sty` and then use `\usepackage{mysec}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course in that case the problem is solved. I use that strategy in my documents...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update (2017-02-14)

The workaround desribed in this answer is not needed anymore if you upgrade to WinEdt 10.2.

WinEdt 10.2 considers all the stuff inside `\newcommand`, `\newenvironment`, `\NewDocumentCommand` and alike like *"verbatim"* stuff, that is nothing inside them is collected in its Tree and Gather interfaces and it is not used for folding purposes.

---

### Original answer

This could be done by parsing the argument of sectioning commands like `\section` and labeling commands like `\label`. It is quite simple for those two commands only, but it would require to completely rewrite some configuration files of WinEdt completely for a global solution.

So, I've come up with a different solution. We can define a "virtual highlighting environment" so to let WinEdt think that we are inside a verbatim environment and discard the things gathered inside it.

The "virtual environment" starts with the comment

```
% BEGIN-NO-GATHER
```

and ends with the comment

```
% END-NO-GATHER
```

---

What you need to do in WinEdt is:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. In the "Options Interface", double-click the "Switches" item (`Switches.ini` gets opened)
3. Locate the line

   ```
   SWITCH="% TeX Comment"
   ```

   and, just *before* (that's important!) it, insert the following lines

   ```
   SWITCH="Don't gather"
     ENABLED=1
     MODE_FILTER="TeX|INS;STY;AUX"
     START="%"
     STOP="%"
     HIGHLIGHT_START=1
     STEP_OVER_STOP=1
     HIGHLIGHT_STOP=1
     SCOPE=4
     DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
     STRICT_PRIORITY=0
     PRIORITY=5
     INDENTED=0
     BOLN_ONLY=0
     CASE_SENSITIVE=1
     VERBATIM=1
     START1_TRIGGER=""
     START2_TRIGGER=" BEGIN-NO-GATHER"
     STOP1_TRIGGER=""
     STOP2_TRIGGER=" END-NO-GATHER"
       TEXT_COLOR="xclComment"
       DEFAULT_FONT=1
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

---

Now, simply enclosing the needed code into the above two comments, gives the desired result.

For example, with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

% BEGIN-NO-GATHER
\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{%
\clearpage%
\section{#1}\label{#2}%
}
% END-NO-GATHER

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}\label{sec:first}

A reference to section~\ref{sec:second}.

\section{Another section}\label{sec:second}

A reference to section~\ref{sec:first}.

\end{document}
```

you get the following result in the Tree interface

[image]

I've tested it as much as I can, and I can say that it works without problems in such simple cases, but I can't guarantee that, in very particular cases, it couldn't break the highlighting algorithm of WinEdt, so use it with care...

Comment: Wow, this is great. I've tried it in many documents of mine and works perfectly. I knew that you would have had a solution for this! Thanks very much.

Comment: @Sterry I've spent half of the day thinking of a solution... But I still owe you the bounty you've awarded to me. And anyway, it hasn't been wasted time. Hope that this can be of help for other WinEdt users, too.